# heroku Postgresql bad connection

Tags: postgresql, heroku

When I run `heroku run rials console`, it gives me this error:

> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg.rb:45:in
>   `initialize': could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>   (PG::ConnectionBad)   Is the server running locally and accepting
>     connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

The app works locally Running on Puma and Postgresql which is the same set up as heroku.

Here is the rest of the error message:

```
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg.rb:45:in `new'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg.rb:45:in `connect'
from /app/app/controllers/incomes-to-json.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

I already have the pg gem installed, created a database and migrated it on heroku.

Comment: Are you using localhost or IP address for connectivity details? If you're using anything that's not localhost you'll need to modify the pg_hba.conf.

Comment: Not sure where to find this pg_hba.conf file.  I just searched my system for /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg.rb and it is not even on my file, could it be on the heroku server?